# Añadir elementos a un numpyarray

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo un *numpy array* con `shape(1024,1023)`, necesito añadir elementos de tal forma que el *numpy array* tenga `shape(1024,1024)`.
¿Es eso posible?

Comment: Lo siento no entendí tu pregunta, ¿podrías ser mas especifico y/o proporcionar un ejemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que puedes usar la función de `numpy` que se llama [append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) así:

```
>>> zeros = np.zeros((10,9))
>>> zeros.shape
(10, 9)
>>> ones  = np.ones((10,1))
>>> cat = np.append(zeros, ones, axis=1)
>>> cat.shape
(10, 10)
```